# C# WCF client Memory leak on XP

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have a problem. I have coded a wcf client (WPF and c#) that is using wsHttpBinding.
And I´m using duplex. I have a function that i call the wcf service every minute called KeepConnection.
And i never close the client proxy because i need to have the client "online" all the time for service callbacks. But when running this client on Windows XP i have a strange problem with the memory of my application.When running normally on win 7 /vista the application only uses 40mb of memory in taskmanger. In Xp in constantly increase the use of memory every second.
I got over 700mb on 2 days.

Is there a way to fix this or is it XP related. Thanks for help.

Service code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Just an empty method for client to keep the connection alive with the service.
    /// </summary>
    public void KeepConnection()
    {
        _logger.Debug("Keep alive requested.");
    }
```

My client code.

```
    private InstanceContext instanceContext; //Wcf instance context for callbacks.

    public static BootDialog _bootScreen = new BootDialog(); //Boot window.
    public static RetryDialog _retryScreen = new RetryDialog(); //Retry window.

    public static ProductionServiceClient service; //Wcf service client

    public static ClientCallBack clientBack; //Client callback events and handler.
    public static ClientTokenResponse ClientToken; //ClientToken from wcf service.
    public static int[] ScannerNumbers;
    public static IList<HighlightArticleDto> highListArticleList; //List and color of witch list to highligt.
    private static readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private static ClientTokenRequest clientRequest;
    private Timer _keepAliveTimer = new Timer();

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        _logger.Trace("Enter Application_Startup().");

        int[] scannerNumberList = ParseHandler.GetScannersFromSettingString(Settings.Default.Scanners);

        //Saves it globally
        App.ScannerNumbers = scannerNumberList;

        _logger.Info("Getting {0} scanners for this client.", scannerNumberList.Count());

        clientBack = new ClientCallBack();
        instanceContext = new InstanceContext(clientBack);

        //ToDO : This fix is for XP computer with the http://+:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/c269764e-808e-4284-ad7f-4e0eb88ee951/ error.
        WSDualHttpBinding binding = new WSDualHttpBinding();
        binding.Name = "WsDualTcpEndpoint";
        binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
        binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
        //binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
        binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
        binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
        binding.TransactionFlow = false;
        binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
        binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536;
        binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
        binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
        binding.Security.Mode = WSDualHttpSecurityMode.None;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("http://").Append(GetLocalIp()).Append(":808/WSDualOnXP");

        _logger.Debug("Client base address : {1}.", sb.ToString());

        binding.ClientBaseAddress = new Uri(sb.ToString());

        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(Settings.Default.ServerAddress);
        service = new ProductionServiceClient(instanceContext, binding, endpoint);

        //2011-08-25 Test utav clientbase
        //service = new ProductionServiceClient(instanceContext, "WsDualTcpEndpoint", Settings.Default.ServerAddress);

        _logger.Debug("Server address : {0}.", Settings.Default.ServerAddress);

        //ToDo Disabled GeneralDialog.
        //2011-05-25 Remove this comment if generaldialog wants to be seen.
        //if (scannerNumberList.Count() == 0 || String.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.Default.ServerAddress))
        //{
        //    GeneralDialog dialog = new GeneralDialog();
        //    dialog.Show();
        //    return;
        //}

        //Subscribe to wcf service.
        SubscribeToService(scannerNumberList);

        //Keep connection to the service alive.
        KeepAlive();

        //Start timer for highlight list
        GetHighLightListTimer();

        //Catch unhandled exceptions
        this.DispatcherUnhandledException += new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(App_DispatcherUnhandledException);
    }

    private void KeepAlive()
    {
        _keepAliveTimer.Interval = 31000;
        _keepAliveTimer.Elapsed +=
                        (
            (object o, ElapsedEventArgs args) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    _keepAliveTimer.Stop();

                    if (service.State != CommunicationState.Opened)
                    {
                        if (service != null) { service.Abort(); }
                        ShowRetryDialog();
                        RetryToSubscribe();
                    }

                    service.KeepConnection();
                }
                catch (TimeoutException ex)
                {
                    if (service != null) { service.Abort(); }

                    ShowRetryDialog();
                    RetryToSubscribe();
                }
                catch (CommunicationException ex)
                {
                    if (service.State != CommunicationState.Opened)
                    {
                        if (service != null) { service.Abort(); }

                        ShowRetryDialog();
                        RetryToSubscribe();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    if (service != null) { service.Abort(); }
                    _keepAliveTimer.Stop();

                    ShowRetryDialog();
                    RetryToSubscribe();
                }
                finally
                {
                    _keepAliveTimer.Start();
                }
            }
        );

        _keepAliveTimer.Start();
    }
```

And My client Callbacks.

```
    #region ClientCallBacks
    //When service callbacks to the client this methods will be triggered.

    void clientBack_ClientNotified(object sender, ClientNotifiedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void clientBack_RemoveFromDisplayEvent(object sender, RemoveFromDisplayEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.Info("Remove from display.");

            userControlChairs.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                _queueProductionItems.Remove(e.OrderResponse);
            }));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void clientBack_AddToDisplayEvent(object sender, AddToDisplayEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.Info("Add to display.");

            userControlChairs.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                _queueProductionItems.Add(e.OrderResponse);
            }));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void clientBack_UpdateQueueDisplayEvent(object sender, UpdateQueueDisplayEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.Info("Update queue display.");

            userControlQueue.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                _queueDisplayItems.Clear();
                foreach (OrderDto o in e.UnfinishedOrdersResponse.Orders)
                {
                    _queueDisplayItems.Add(o);
                }

            }));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private ObservableOrderResponseQueue _queueProductionItems = new ObservableOrderResponseQueue(); //List of the chairs that will be displayed.
    private ObservableCollection<ErrorMessage> _errorMessages = new ObservableCollection<ErrorMessage>(); //List that holds the error message for debug 
    private ObservableCollection<OrderDto> _queueDisplayItems = new ObservableCollection<OrderDto>();//List of order and quanities left. (DisplayQueue).
    private ObservableCollection<DebugInfo> _queueDebugInfo = new ObservableCollection<DebugInfo>(); //
```

RetryToSubsribe method.

```
        public void RetryToSubscribe()
    {

        try
        {
            WSDualHttpBinding binding = new WSDualHttpBinding();
            binding.Name = "WsDualTcpEndpoint";
            binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
            binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
            //binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
            binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
            binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
            binding.TransactionFlow = false;
            binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
            binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536;
            binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
            binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
            binding.Security.Mode = WSDualHttpSecurityMode.None;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("http://").Append(GetLocalIp()).Append(":808/WSDualOnXP");

            _logger.Debug("Client base address : {1}.", sb.ToString());

            binding.ClientBaseAddress = new Uri(sb.ToString());

            EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(Settings.Default.ServerAddress);

            service = new ProductionServiceClient(instanceContext, binding, endpoint);

            ClientTokenRequest request = new ClientTokenRequest();
            request.RequestId = NewRequestId;
            request.StationNumbers = ScannerNumbers;

            clientRequest = request;

            service.Subscribe(request);

            //Close the retry window.
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                //Set the background to default.
                this.MainWindow.SetResourceReference(Window.BackgroundProperty, "MainBackground");

                _retryScreen.Hide();
            }));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680289/wcf-memory-usage

Comment: Thanks for the url. But my service doesnt have any issues. Only at client side. But do i need to close the proxy ? If i close it will the callback works ?.

Comment: As far as I understand with Duplex in effect your client becomes a service too with it's own channel stack. So if you close the channel from the client to the service the callback channel should still be open.

Comment: @Tan: Without any code, it's impossible to tell.  Please post some service and more importantly, client code, with your callback setup and what is in the callback.

Comment: But the weird thing is that in only happens in Windows XP. in Windows 7 the memory usage doesnt increase.

Comment: @hugh jadick: Are you sure it works that way. Do you have any links i can read about it thanks!

Comment: If you think logically about this it makes sense. The callback interface is defined as a separate service contract, so this must constructed with it's own channel.

Comment: @hugh jadick: I tested to close all the calls to the service. The communication state was faulted so the service couldnt callback.

Comment: @tan - thanks for doing that. I stand corrected.

Comment: Have you profiled the memory usage of your application with a memory profiler in win xp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can run windbg and follow along you might find out what exactly is leaking.

- on your winxp machine open windbg and attach to the client process(let it run for a while to magnify the problem, i.e. the memory leak)
- at the prompt type

> ```
> If using .NET 2/3.5
> .loadby sos mscorwks
> If using .NET 4 
> .loadby sos clr
> ```

- then run

> !dumpheap -stat

you'll get a list of all the objects in memory grouped by class. look for the ones that have the most number of instances. Hopefully that will give you an indication of what is the offending code.

other options are:

> !dumpheap -stat -type
>   MyClass*

this will show you only instances of classes that start with MyClass.

Do not close windbg before detaching from the process otherwise it will kill your process.

Comment: I tried using windbg and did find that System.String had 65000 objects.But the weird thing is when i attach my application to windbg the memory of the app didnt increase.but it increase again after detaching the app from windbg.

Comment: string and object instances can be ignored unless that is a huge number (you need to decide what a huge number is for you case). What was the total size of your strings? You could also be leaking unmanaged memory due to not disposing disposable resources.

Comment: I dont have unmanaged code. The application is only calling wcf services. it is using events and ObservableCollection and INotifyCollectionChanged. Can those objects leak memory ? and it seems only virtual memory is increaseing.

Comment: every I/O operation you do in .net has some unmanaged resources allocated. your wcf channels are using unmanaged resources that is why you need to close them as soon as you are done. A timer has a reference to a kernel object as well. Most cases of unmanaged memory leaks are .NET framework bugs, not much you can do about them. Can I ask why you need to keep your service alive? What is wrong with polling? Do you have a real-time application?

Comment: Yeah i have a real time application. And the client computer only shuts down once a week. I cant use polling methods because i need the duplex. The services is processing some xml files and sends out the information to the clients. Duplex doesnt work if i dispose my service client.

Comment: You need to post all the code so we can help. One other option is to create a separate appdomain that is connected to the service and recycle it on regular basis.

Comment: Its quite a much code. Dont think i can post it all up. Is there a chance i can email it to you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the memory leak occurs in the timer's Elapsed handler. Can you post the code for RetryToSubscribe().

Comment: Edited the post with RetryToSubscribe()

Comment: You're not disposing anything in the RetryToSubscribe and you possibly should unregister your events.

Comment: BUt if i dispose my service or unregister my events the duplex wont work. My application need to be always on. And need to be real time.